# Firebase Scheduled notification not sending notification daily

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I have scheduled a push notification for my Android App, for a month at 11.00 am daily using the firebase console. It sends the notification if I send it now. But if I schedule it for daily, it comes for 2-3 in the beginning but after that, there is no notification. What is this bug, please help.

Comment: Do you know Firebase Functions?
You can achieve this thing using Firebase cloud functions instead of Mobile Device.

Comment: No, but I'll check that out. @ParthPatel

Comment: @AdhishMathur, any updates?

Answer (score 2):

you can use cron jobs basically it allows to schedule functions on specific time intervals
Firebase cloud functions have recently introduced this functionality.
Take a look at this url 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions